# Перенаправлять ввод и вывод из subshell

Tags: shell, linux

Нужно написать скрипт, который бы открыл в отдельном процессе ssh соединение, и потом перенаправлял ввод/вывод оттуда с незначительными изменениями на консоль.  т.е. я представляю это себе как некоторый `while` цикл, который бы каждую (почти каждую) команду перенаправлял в ssh и возвращал оттуда ответ.  Необходимо это сделать стандартными средствами shell, так, чтобы оно запустилось на android busybox. (утилита ssh присутствует)  Основной вопрос в том, как в дочерний процесс передавать команды и получать ответ? Ещё раз, логика такая:

1. запускается команда `ssh xxx@xx.xx.xx.xx ghci`
2. ssh требует пароль и я его ввожу, после чего запускается внутренняя консоль ghci
3. вводятся различные команды haskell

Но основная проблема в том, что **не все команды нужно сразу передавать по ssh в ghci**, а некоторые нужно сначала обработать по-особому на стороне клиента и только потом передать. Поэтому я думаю, что нужно скрипте сделать так, чтобы он создавал дочерний процесс и в нём подключался, а в основном процессе совершал взаимодействие с пользователем и передачу команд/вывода в дочерний процесс.

Comment: Мне и нужен пример, потому что я не могу его написать :) Дописал побольше пояснений, прошу прощения за кривоту описания проблемы :)

Comment: Вот это еще поясните " сначала обработать по-особому на стороне клиента и только потом передать. "

Comment: ну например, если команда пользователя abc, то переслать на сервер abcd, а если  :q, то послать сначала :q, а затем сразу exit

Comment: Что то мне кажется вы выбрали не правильное направление решения задачи, исходную бы проблему услышать, просто то что вы хотите сделать мне до сих пор толком не понятно, но самое главное зачем?

Comment: Ок. Исходная задача:  Сделать sh скрипт для запуска в эмуляторе терминала Android, который бы подключился по ssh к моему серверу, запустил там ghci и позволил мне выполнять команды.В ghci есть команда :l module которая позволяет загрузить модуль из текстового файла. Я её хочу перегрузить так в этом скрипте, чтобы этот самый файл отправлялся по ssh с планшета на сервер, а потом запускался там

Comment: Так вы сначала загрузите файл а потом уже запускайте ghci , не?

Comment: Ну для этого я бы не заходил специально на форум чтобы задать вопрос, не?

Answer (score 1):

мне это ТЗ напоминает [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)

Comment: Именно! Забыл про него написать. Но, к сожалению, в комплект buxybox он не входит, и я не нашёл его под андроид, а скомпилировать самому не хватает знаний.

Comment: а аппарат с андроидом очень слабый? может там развести линукс в ченджруте? там будут все прелести

Answer (score 0):

scp для передачи файлов не подойдет в данном случае (не уверен в наличии в busybox scp)? Подключение ssh по ключам не поможет? Может и не в тему ляпаю, но всё-же ;)

Answer (score 0):

> 2) ssh требует пароль и я его ввожу

всё, после этого вы общаетесь уже с удалённой машиной.

и никакими «стандарными средствами shell» вы уже не сможете вмешаться в этот диалог.

Comment: ssh умеет выполнять команды и результат возвращать хост машине с которой она запущена например: ssh hostname df -h. А если прописать ключи в соответствующих файлах то и пароль вводить не надо.